# How to make a toggle cell in GTK TreeView editable by using Glade?

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, glade

I'm using Glade 3.20 but i don't known how to make a toggle column editable. I do not see any options.
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqWA9.png)

Please help me!

Comment: Try deselecting the activatable checkbutton and turning the switch on (if it's off) that appears. Then you need to connect to the 'toggled' signal. Toggle renderers do not have a popup renderer like some of the other renderers.

Comment: It's works, thank you theGtknerd

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [CellRendererToggle usage example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#cellrenderertoggle)  (in python).

The source (in case the link breaks someday):

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class CellRendererToggleWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererToggle Example")

        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, bool, bool)
        self.liststore.append(["Debian", False, True])
        self.liststore.append(["OpenSuse", True, False])
        self.liststore.append(["Fedora", False, False])

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(column_text)

        renderer_toggle = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
        renderer_toggle.connect("toggled", self.on_cell_toggled)

        column_toggle = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Toggle", renderer_toggle, active=1)
        treeview.append_column(column_toggle)

        renderer_radio = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
        renderer_radio.set_radio(True)
        renderer_radio.connect("toggled", self.on_cell_radio_toggled)

        column_radio = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Radio", renderer_radio, active=2)
        treeview.append_column(column_radio)

        self.add(treeview)

    def on_cell_toggled(self, widget, path):
        self.liststore[path][1] = not self.liststore[path][1]

    def on_cell_radio_toggled(self, widget, path):
        selected_path = Gtk.TreePath(path)
        for row in self.liststore:
            row[2] = (row.path == selected_path)

win = CellRendererToggleWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```